# Error starting autostart for iOS on x-platform calabash

Tags: ios, ruby, automated-tests, cucumber

When I run the test, I write the following error in the console:

```
undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
  /Users/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/run_loop 1.2.6/lib/run_loop/sim_control.rb:866:in `block in sim_details'
  /Users/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/run_loop-1.2.6/lib/run_loop/sim_control.rb:863:in `each'
  /Users/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/run_loop-1.2.6/lib/run_loop/sim_control.rb:863:in `sim_details'
  /Users/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/run_loop-1.2.6/lib/run_loop/sim_control.rb:290:in `enable_accessibility_on_sims'
  /Users/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/run_loop-1.2.6/lib/run_loop/core.rb:214:in `run_with_options'
  /Users/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/run_loop-1.2.6/lib/run_loop/core.rb:792:in `run'
  /Users/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.12.2/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:755:in `block in new_run_loop'
  /Users/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.12.2/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:753:in `times'
  /Users/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.12.2/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:753:in `new_run_loop'
  /Users/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.12.2/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:624:in `relaunch'
  /Users/denis/Documents/calabash-test-ios/x-platform-example/features/ios/support/01_launch.rb:27:in `Before'
```

The test itself is an [example](https://github.com/calabash/x-platform-example/) from here. Here is the code for one of the errors:

```
def sim_details(primary_key)
  unless xcode_version_gte_6?
    raise RuntimeError, 'this method is only available on Xcode >= 6'
  end

  allowed = [:udid, :launch_name]
  unless allowed.include? primary_key
    raise ArgumentError, "expected '#{primary_key}' to be one of '#{allowed}'"
  end

  hash = {}
  xctools.instruments(:sims).each do |elm|
    launch_name = elm[/\A.+\((\d\.\d(\.\d)? Simulator\))/, 0]
    udid = elm[XCODE_6_SIM_UDID_REGEX,0]
    sdk_version = elm[/(\d\.\d(\.\d)? Simulator)/, 0].split(' ').first
    value =
          {
                :launch_name => launch_name,
                :udid => udid,
                :sdk_version => RunLoop::Version.new(sdk_version)
          }
    if primary_key == :udid
      key = udid
    else
      key = launch_name
    end
    hash[key] = value
  end
  hash
end
```

Run this command: `bundle exec cucumber -p ios DEVICE_TARGET="6D45E1...6513"`

Can anyone come across?

Comment: can you include the code around the line that is causing the above error?

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden code added

Answer (score 0):

Does the DEVICE_TARGET UUID actually exist in the list of available simulators?
`instruments -s` will show you the devices. Switching Xcode versions and not rebooting or restarting the CoreSimulator service can result in the simulator not being found.

Comment: DEVICE_TARGET UUID is actually

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this code `sdk_version = elm[/(\d\.\d(\.\d)? Simulator)/, 0]` is not returning anything. It seems that you are expecting it to return a string.  I would debug in that area.

The error is telling you that your selection is resulting in a nil object which of course has no class, and also as such has no `.split` method.  As a result trying to invoke the `.split` method is giving you the error that the thing you have there, does not have a .split method defined.